# Mocking subprocess.check_call more than once

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have a function that calls `subprocess.check_call()` twice. I want to test all their possible outputs. I want to be able to set the first `check_call()` to return 1 and the second to return 0 and to do so for all possible combinations. The below is what I have so far. I am not sure how to adjust the expected return value

```
@patch('subprocess.check_call')
def test_hdfs_dir_func(mock_check_call):
    for p, d in list(itertools.product([1, 0], repeat=2)):
        if p or d:
```

Comment: what about just storing the previous state with a toggle (global variable)

Comment: general note: you don't need to force iteration just do `for p, d in itertools.product([1, 0], repeat=2):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the `side_effect` of your mock to an iterable and that will return the next value in the iterable each time it's called. In this case, you could do something like this:

```
import copy
import itertools
import subprocess

from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('subprocess.check_call')
def test_hdfs_dir_func(mock_check_call):
    return_values = itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=2)
    # Flatten the list; only one return value per call
    mock_check_call.side_effect = itertools.chain.from_iterable(copy.copy(return_values))
    for p, d in return_values:
        assert p == subprocess.check_call()
        assert d == subprocess.check_call()
```

Note a few things:

- I don't have your original functions so I put my own calls to `check_call` in the loop.
- I'm using copy on the original `itertools.product` return value because if I don't, it uses the original iterator. This exhausts that original iterator when what we want is 2 separate lists: one for the mock's side_effect and one for you to loop through in your test.
- You can do other neat stuff with `side_effect`, not just raise. As shown above, you can change the return value for multiple calls: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#side-effect-functions-and-iterables

  - Not only that, but you can see from the link above that you can also give it a function pointer. That allows you to do even more complex logic when keeping track of multiple mock calls.